# Stubhub api image url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the stubhub api and would like to use the image_url attribute that is given back for each event object.  Currently, the api is returning a string that looks like this for an image:

```
"stubhub_472291_MortonMeyerson_Concert.png"
```

I'd like to be able to interpolate this in my rails app so that I have the correct url for each image.

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://www.stubhub.com/data/venue_maps/#{event.geography_parent}/#{event.image_url}"
```

Comment: I am using this URL but there is no image element present in the response.  What API are you using?
 https://api.stubhub.com/sellers/search/events/v3?country=us&dateLastModified=2020-12-20T12:00&start=0&rows=500